# purrr::walk is a noop but purr::map with identical arguments is not

Tags: r, ggplot2, lazy-evaluation, purrr

For some reason, with identical arguments, `purrr::walk` and `purrr::map` exhibit different behavior.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

suv <- mpg %>% filter(class == "suv")
compact <- mpg %>% filter(class == "compact")

purrr::walk(list(suv, compact), ~ggplot(.,aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point())
# No output

purrr::map(list(suv, compact), ~ggplot(.,aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point())
# Generates two plots
```

From looking at the `purrr` source code, I can tell that  `walk` is just a wrapper around `map` that invisibly returns the `.x` argument:

```r
purrr::walk <- function(.x, .f, ...)
{
    map(.x, .f, ...)
    invisible(.x)
}
```

For that reason, I can't understand why the behavior would be different. Does this have something to do with lazy-evaluation? Is the fact that the return value of `map` isn't being used preventing `.f` from being evaluated?

Comment: Well, the `ggplot()` object doesn't actually draw a plot. It creates a ggplot object. That object is only rendered to a plot when you `print()` that object. Normally when you run a command in R, the result is automatically printed for you by the console. But when you do a `walk`, nothing is printed() so you get no plots (but the `ggplot` function did all the work of calculating the information for the plot). You can add a `print()` around the `ggplot()` in the walk to get it to render.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.